# Problem with select when closing socket

Tags: c, sockets, select

I'm doing a multiclient server that accepts a connection, forks, and gives the connection to the child so it can handle it. It's a multiclient server, so it has multiple children.

The main process is in an infinite `while` which makes a `select` to find out if there is a new incoming connection or if a child is trying to communicate.

The problem arises when I close a client (which is connected to a son of the main server):
it randomly happens that the client connection is closed, and the select gets unblocked because supposedly the internal socket (which handles the incoming connection between the children and the main server) was modified, but as far as I am concerned that is not true.
What actually happened was that the client closed the connection and the child just died.

Can anyone give me a clue of what it's going on here? I'm quite lost.

This is the code of the infinite loop in the main server:

```
while (1) {
    /*inicializo variables para el select*/
    sflag = 0;
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    FD_SET(sockfd, &readfds);
    FD_SET(sockifd,&readfds);
    max = (sockfd > sockifd) ? sockfd : sockifd;
    for(aux = isockets; aux != NULL; aux = aux -> next){
        FD_SET(aux -> sd, &readfds);
        max = (max > aux -> sd) ? max : aux -> sd;
    }

    printf("pre-select\n");
    select(max + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    /*checkeo si salio por actividad en un socket interno*/
    for (aux = isockets; aux != NULL; aux = aux -> next){
        if (FD_ISSET(aux -> sd, &readfds)){
            printf("comunicacion con el socket: %d\n", aux -> sd);
            sflag = 1;
            actsocket = aux -> sd;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (sflag == 1){//mensaje de un hijo
        n = recv(actsocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
        if (n == 0) {
            printf("conexion cerrada con el socket interno: %d\n", actsocket);
            close(actsocket);
            isockets = free_sock(isockets, actsocket);
            printf("isockets: %p\n", isockets);
        }
        else if(n < 0) error ("ERROR en comunicacion interna");
        else printf("mensaje del boludon: %s\n", buffer);
    }   
    else if (FD_ISSET(sockifd, &readfds)){// un hijo inicia conexion interna
        printf("antes de accpet interno\n");
        newisockfd = accept(sockifd, (struct sockaddr *) &ucli_addr, &uclilen);
        printf("nueva conexion interna, socketfd: %d\n", newisockfd);
        isockets = add_socket(isockets,newisockfd, 0);
        recorre(isockets);
        if (newisockfd < 0) error ("ERROR en accept unix, padre");
    }
    else if (FD_ISSET (sockfd, &readfds)){/*conexion entrante*/
        printf("conexion entrante\n");
        newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);
            if (newsockfd < 0) error("ERROR on accept");
            pid = fork();

        if (pid < 0) error("ERROR on fork");
            if (pid == 0){//hijo
                    close(sockfd);
            dostuff(newsockfd, path, tm,fd[0]);
                    exit(0);

            }
            else {  //padre
            printf("conexion aceptada, pid hijo %d\n", pid);
            close(newsockfd);
        }
    }
    }
```

So, randomly, when I close a connection, the select unblock as if "sockifd" was modified, but it wasn't. Don't know why is doing that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One thing that is wrong in your code is that you're not checking the return value of `select`.

If `select` is interrupted by a signal (returns `-1` with `errno = EINTR`, for example `SIGCHLD` if one of the children died), then the contents of `&readfds` is undefined, and thus must not be read. (See for example the Linux man page for [`select`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/select.2.html).)

So check the return value if `select`, and loop right back to it without going through the `&readfds` processing if there's a temporary error like `EINTR`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot for that remark Mat, it was actually that, there was an interruption that was unblocking the select, I solve it with this (there are more ways to do it of course):

```
repeat_select:
if((err = select (max + 1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, NULL)) < 0)
    if (errno == EINTR) //a signal has interrupted the select, so I restarted it
        goto repeat_select;
    else
        //another error, handle it as you want
```

I hope this would be useful for someone with the same problem =)

Answer (score 0):

When the child closes the socket connection the select will unblock and the "recv" will return 0. So you should always check the return value from the "recv" function to determine whether the connection is closed or not.